# Routes: redirect to a separate page

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, angular-ui-router

I have this in app component html:

```
 <h1 class="title">{{ title | uppercase }}</h1>
 <app-discography-container></app-discography-container>
 <app-total-albums></app-total-albums>
 <app-single-album></app-single-album>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

then i have another component named `video` with route declared in app-module:

```
 const routes: Routes = [{ path: 'video', component: VideoComponent }];
```

and in `app-discography` component i have this:

```
 <a routerLink="/video" target="_blank">
   lorem ipsum 
 </a>
```

When I click on the link "lorem ipsum", I redirect to the video path, but with me I also have the components `app-total-albums` and `app-single-album` and instead I don't want them... I would like it to redirect me to a separate page

Comment: what is your angular version? In subscription I'm taking the current route path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think I understand your issue. You don't want to show app-total-albums and app-single-album components in video page. So I have made one stackblitz link for your scenario please check and let me know if this is what you required.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fhpdqy?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: is exactly what I was looking for! thank you so much! could you explain to me what you did? I did not understand the part of `this.router.events` from where you use `NavigationEnd` onwards...

Comment: what is your angular version? is that issue resolved in your local?  whenever routing ends in angular we can get that information using that subscription. So I'm getting current url path as /videos.. so based on that I'm hiding those two extra components in app.component.html.